# Backpressuring Snowflake using "rowStreamHighWaterMark" in snowflake-sdk?

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I'm using [snowflake-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snowflake-sdk) and [snowflake-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snowflake-promise) to stream results (to avoid loading too many objects in memory).

For each streamed row, I want to process the received information (an ETL-like job that performs write-backs). My code is quite basic and similar to this simplistic [snowflake-promise example](https://github.com/natesilva/snowflake-promise/blob/HEAD/examples/streaming.js).

My current problem is that `.on('data', ...)` is called more often than I can manage to handle. (My ETL-like job can't keep up with the received rows and my DB connection pool to perform write-backs gets exhausted).

I tried setting [rowStreamHighWaterMark](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-nodejs/blob/bd6e283411697e121271e59bc66582917c20156e/lib/connection/connection_config.js#L714) to various values (1, 10 [default], 100, 1000, 2000 and 4000) in an effort to *slow down*/backpressure [stream.Readable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streamreadable) but, unfortunately, it didn't change anything.

What did I miss ? How can I better control when to *consume* the read data ?

Answer (score 0):

If this was written synchronous, you would see that to "be pushed too much data" than you can handled to write at the same time" cannot happen because:

```
while(data){
    data.readrow()
    doSomethineAwesome()
    writeDataViaPoolTheBacksUp()
}
```

just can not spin to fast.

Now if you are accepting data on one async thread, and pushing that data onto a queue and draining the queue in another async thread, you will get the problem you discribe (that is your queue explodes). So you need to slow/pause the completion of the read's thread when the write thread is too behind.

Given to is writing to the assumed queue, when that gets too long, stop.

The other way you might be doing this is with no work queue, but fire a async write each time conditions are meet. This is bad because you have no track of outstand work, and you are doing many small updates to the DB, which if is Snowflake it really dislikes. A better approach would be to build a local set of data changes, we will call it a batch, and when you batch get to a size you flush the changes set in one operation (and you flush the batch when input is completed, to catch the dregs)

Answer (score 0):

The Snowflake support got back to me with an answer.

They told me to create the connection this way:

```
  var connection = snowflake.createConnection({
    account: "testaccount",
    username: "testusername",
    password: "testpassword",
    rowStreamHighWaterMark: 5
  });
```

**Full disclaimer**: My project has changed and I could NOT recreate the problem on my local environment. I couldn't assess the answer's validity; still, I wanted to share in case somebody could get some hints from this information.